# how to draw a bar chart along with the line graph in mimchart library iPhone?

Tags: ipad

Can you suggest me for this? my code is here........

```
mWallGraph=[[MIMWallGraph alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 200, self.view.frame.size.width-90, self.view.frame.size.width * 0.6)];
mWallGraph.delegate=self;
mWallGraph.anchorTypeArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NONE],
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:NONE],
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:NONE],
                            nil];

mWallGraph.xTitleStyle=X_TITLES_STYLE3;
[mWallGraph drawMIMWallGraph];
[self.view addSubview:mWallGraph];
```

all delegate methods are defined for values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
myBarChart=[[MIMBarGraph alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 20, self.view.frame.size.width-50, self.view.frame.size.width * 0.3)];
            myBarChart.delegate=self;
            myBarChart.xTitleStyle=XTitleStyle3;
            //myBarChart.margin=MIMMarginMake(30, 40, 0, 50);
            myBarChart.gradientStyle=VERTICAL_GRADIENT_STYLE;

            [myBarChart drawBarChart];
            [self.view addSubview:myBarChart];
```

or you can go for [core-plot library](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) for showing graph in your app instead of Mim

Comment: this code is not working Viruss mca. i have a requirement like i have to draw a bar chart according to the y-axis on the left and another line graph according to the y-axis on the right side.On a single view i have to draw both.. can you help me?